# URL encoding back to true URL

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have these URLs:

```
http://www.jobbsafari.se/jobbsoekning?q=trainers.php%253Fid%253D'%2Band''
http://www.jobbsafari.se/jobbsoekning?q=trainers.php?id%253D%2Band'
http://tay-sen.com.ua/trainers.php?id=12%26action=show_photos%26m_lang_id=9'
```

I need to code them back to their true URL. Right now I'm using:

```
string = ARGV[0]
string.gsub("%25", '%').gsub("%53", "S").gsub(etc..)
```

Is there a better way to do multiple `gsub`ing without having to do `.gsub.gsub.gsub`?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @sawa I agree with you but if I don't "reinvent the wheel" the program this is meant for fails everytime.

Comment: @sawa that's okay, you dot need to get me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `uri`:

```
require 'uri'
URI.decode(your_url)
```

It will replace all of the URI encoding.

Comment: @13aal we are here to help you ;)

Comment: @13aal It would be good if you accept the answer. :) SO way to say thanks. ;)

Comment: [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) isn't a gem, it's part of Ruby's standard-library.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri, It isn't good to accept an answer right away, especially when there's only one answer. Several hours are a starting point and I recommend 24 hours, since that gives people around the world time to respond. You should read the accepted answer in meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297597/128421

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for sharing the link. I asked to accept the answer because OP had found it useful and resolved his issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your URLs contain queries that have been encoded multiple times.

If the encoding occurred once you're OK, but when you have multiple layers it can get messy:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://tay-sen.com.ua/trainers.php?id=12%26action=show_photos%26m_lang_id=9")
query = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h
query  # => {"id"=>"12&action=show_photos&m_lang_id=9"}

URI.decode_www_form(query['id']).to_h
# => {"12"=>"", "action"=>"show_photos", "m_lang_id"=>"9"}
```

Comment: Okay, and how does his answer my question? If I have a hash of decoded URL, then what do I do with it from there..?

Comment: It helps answer the question by telling you there are dragons ahead of you. You need to be aware that pages do contain multiple-encoded URLs and if you are trying to get back to the original URL you'll have to peel back layers. There is no method that'll do it for you; They can do the first decode but you have to be able to tell whether further decoding is necessary. It's not hard to figure out how to iteratively decode then check.

Comment: That makes sense to me, thank you for the information.